# uninitialized local variable bypassing cin statement

Tags: c++, variables, c++11, cin

Consider the following code:

```
int n;
if(!cin>>n)
{
    cin.clear();
    while(cin.get()!='\n')
        continue;
}
cout<<n;
```

The output is:

```
0
```

Why there was no any prompt on the terminal for typing the input value for `n`? And why uninitialized `n` is set to `0` automatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Logic NOT operator `!` has higher precedence than bitwise-shift operator `>>`. If `cin` is not in error state, `!cin` will become `false` and `!cin>>n` will be zero when `n` is zero. Use parentheses to check if reading was successful. I guess `n` happened to be zero.

```
int n;
if(!(cin>>n))
{
    cin.clear();
    while(cin.get()!='\n')
        continue;
}
cout<<n;
```

Comment: Did you mean !cin turns to 0 (false) and this 0 is entered into the n by the istream operator?

Comment: @dlpsankhla No. No istream operator is used in the condition and `n` will remain uninitialized.

Comment: Then how can a local variable initialized to 0 by default?

Comment: @dlpsankhla If the variable is a class type, by the default constructor (including initializer list). If the variables is a scalar type, by chance. [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 8.5 Initializers, paragraph 11 says: "If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized; if no initialization is performed, an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value."

Comment: @dlpsankhla Make the local scalar variable static to have it zero-initialized to have value 0.